# How to efficiently left outer join two sorted lists

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two lists which are already sorted. I need to left outer join them. The following code gets the job done:

```
left_sorted_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
right_sorted_list = [[2, 21], [4, 45], [6, 67]]
right_dict = {r[0]: r[1] for r in right_sorted_list}
left_outer_join = [[l, right_dict[l] if l in right_dict.keys() else None]
                   for l in left_sorted_list]
print(left_outer_join)
[[1, None], [2, 21], [3, None], [4, 45], [5, None]]
```

However, I am not sure if this approach is very efficient. Is there a more efficient way to utilize the fact that the right list is already sorted, without writing loops?

**Edit:** the keys I am joining on are unique both in left and right lists.

Comment: `right_dict = dict(right_sorted_list)` would work too...

Comment: Also, on python2.x, `if l in right_dict.keys()` is quite inefficient.  `if l in right_dict` is much better.  on python3.x there might not be any major difference between the two aside from the latter being more idiomatic.

Comment: @mgilson thanks! I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way, without a dictionary.

Comment: @A-K Yes there is - walk the lists, with loops :) Or, unless there is a known/verifiable performance issue, just keep the higher-level operations. (The time complexity should be the same in both cases [thanks to C being pulled out and dictionary access assumed to be constant time], although manually walking the sorted lists avoids creating the dictionary and performing the look-back operations - which can result in a smaller wallclock, although it needs testing.)

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, `[[l, right_dict.get(l)] for l in left_sorted_list]` is much clearer.

Comment: As far as efficiency, assuming you make my above suggestions, your algorithm is O(N) + O(M) (where N is the length of left_sorted_list and M is the length of right_sorted_list).  No matter what, you need to walk over both lists (at least until you get to max(left_sorted_list)) so you won't get a whole lot better than what you already have ...

Comment: @mgilson I'll go for your suggestion [[l, right_dict.get(l)] for l in left_sorted_list] - thanks!

Comment: @mgilson: I codified your comments into an answer.  Sorry for the blatant pilfering.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- no problem.  I didn't do it so somebody _should_.  Better to get a "pilfered" accepted answer than to have something un-answered around here :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This answer depends directly on two comments that mgilson made to the OP's question.*

This is no more efficient than what you have, but it is more pythonic.

```
left_sorted_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
right_sorted_list = [[2, 21], [4, 45]]

right_dict = dict(right_sorted_list)
left_outer_join = [[l, right_dict.get(l)] for l in left_sorted_list]
```

As far as time complexity goes, `left_sorted_list` and `right_sorted_list` are each iterated over once so they are both O(N).  For the dictionary look-ups [the average look-up is O(1)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), so looking up all keys is also O(N).  Your time complexity isn't going to get much better than what you already have.

Comment: Something like `d = dict.fromkeys(left_sorted_list);d.update([[2, 21], [4, 45]])` looks better to me.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Correct, except for when the `right_sorted_list` contains keys not in `left_sorted_list`.  Then it wouldn't be a proper left-join.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: it would, because the output is filtered on `left_sorted_list` anyway

Comment: @njzk2: `d.update([[2, 21], [4, 45], [1000, 9999]])` gives `{1: None, 2: 21, 3: None, 4: 45, 5: None, 1000: 9999}` which breaks the concept of left-join with the inclusion of `1000: 9999`.

Comment: Yes, this is much cleaner than my original version. +1 for crediting mgilson.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: but `[[l, right_dict.get(l)] for l in left_sorted_list]` contains only elements from the `left_sorted_list` anyway

Comment: @njz2:  That is true of my updated answer, but not true of the answer from when you added your original comment.  But I quibble ...

Comment: It is more efficient (at least on python2.x) because `right_dict.get(l)` is O(1) whereas `l in right_dict.keys()` is O(len(right_dict)).

Answer (score 5):

Here's memory-efficient version that produces one key/value pair at a time:

```
def left_outer_join(keys, pairs, default=None):
    right = iter(pairs)
    right_key = float('-inf') # sentinel: any left key must be larger than it
    for left_key in keys:
        if left_key == right_key: # *keys* and *right* are in sync
            value = right_value  # from previous iteration
        elif left_key < right_key: # *keys* is behind *right*
            value = default
        else: # left_key > right_key: *keys* is ahead of *right*
            for right_key, right_value in right: # catch up with *keys*
                if left_key <= right_key: # drop while left_key > right_key
                    break
            value = right_value if left_key == right_key else default
        yield left_key, value
```

It is `O(n+m)` single pass algorithm.

Example:

```
left_sorted_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
right_sorted_list = [[2, 21], [4, 45], [6, 67]]
print(list(left_outer_join(left_sorted_list, right_sorted_list)))
# -> [(1, None), (2, 21), (3, None), (4, 45), (5, None)]
```

`keys` and `pairs` can be unlimited sorted iterators (such as produced by `heapq.merge()` function) of keys and key/value pairs correspondingly.

Comment: +1 This works as long as the keys we are joining on are unique both in left and right lists. This is the case. I edited my question to explicitly state that. Thank you!

Comment: @A-K: I've assumed uniqueness seeing the dictionariy in the question. `itertools.groupby()` or its analog can take care of duplicates.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Sorry ... I lost the first line... Sorry again. Ok, my solution is hard to read. I'll remove it and my wrong comment too.

Answer (score 1):

For result I used tuples, so there is less square brackets ;)

```
left_sorted_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
right_sorted_list = [[2, 21], [4, 45]]

d  = dict(right_sorted_list) # if you have a list of pairs, just pass it to dict()
print [(x, d[x] if x in d else None) for x in left_sorted_list]

## -- End pasted text --
[(1, None), (2, 21), (3, None), (4, 45), (5, None)]
```

Comment: You can use `.get()` in your last line `print [(x, d.get(x)) for x in left_sorted_list]`, if the value is missing `None` is returned by default.

Comment: yes, or `d.setdefault(x, None)`; However it is already in @Steven Rumbalski answer, so no need to duplicate it.